# Functions not created when execute createdtabase() Method Linq Vb.net

Tags: .net, sql-server, database, vb.net, linq

When Create Database by linq all table is created but the **Method(Stored Procedure) and Functions** not Created

```
  Sub createsqldatabase()
        Try
            Using connect As New DataAj(GetSQLConnectionString(True))
                connect.CreateDatabase()
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
           MessageBoxex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

**DataAj:** Name of DataContext
**GetSQLConnectionString(True):** is funtion to get Connection String

```
 Public Function GetSQLConnectionString(ByVal includeDatabase As Boolean) As String
        Dim builder As New SqlConnectionStringBuilder()
        'Build a connection string from the user input.'
        builder.DataSource = Msql.datasource
        builder.IntegratedSecurity = Msql.IntSec
        If builder.IntegratedSecurity = False Then
            builder.UserID = Msql.username
            builder.Password = Msql.password
        End If
        If includeDatabase Then
            builder.InitialCatalog = Msql.DatabaseName
        End If

        Return builder.ConnectionString
    End Function
```

Comment: What is `CreateDatabase` ?

Comment: it is Method  to create a database on the server by linq, it is created by Microsoft Team.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding something; Code First doesn't look at your program and turn all the methods it finds into some translated TSQL set of stored procedures, it just concerns itself with the data aspect; entity names, properties, how they link to each other.. and creates that schema. No stored procs from your methods, though you could configure it to create procs for CRUD ops if you use EF non-core; google "MapToStoredProcedures"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CreateDatabase()
To make things even slicker, since the entity classes know so much about the structure of the database to which they are mapped, Microsoft provides a method named CreateDatabase to actually
create the database.
You should realize, though, that it can only create the parts of the database that it knows about
via the entity class attributes or a mapping file. So, the content of things like stored procedures, triggers, user-defined functions, and check constraints will not be produced in a database created in this
manner, since there are no attributes specifying this information. For simple applications, this may
be perfectly acceptable though.